# pop up when back arrow hit on IE, using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, back-button

I created a button using javascript, which upon hitting would use the history.go(-1) JavaScript function and also pop up a window. hitting the back button on IE already has the built in feature of going back one step into the history, but I also need the pop up to show when a user hits the back button.
Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Showing popups on back? Man, I don't even *want* to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a touchy subject on SO (as it should be). Typically, when a programmer wants to see if the user is clicking the back button or leaving the page, it's for a malicious purpose. Because I think much better of you, user583227, I'll get you started in the right direction: [How to detect if the user clicked the "back" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008806/how-to-detect-if-the-user-clicked-the-back-button)

Comment: well, I need this only for a webpage running on the company intranet.

Comment: @user583227, See, I said I had faith in your intentions. The link I posted should point you in the right direction.