# Is there a way using Jquery to detect the back button being pressed cross browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that is on a slide show and when the user presses the back button I would like it to go back to the album view not the prior and prevent page. Is there a way of doing this? thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery Address provides strong cross-browser support for browser history and Ajax crawling:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address

http://github.com/asual/jquery-address

Greetings

**UPDATE:**

you can find a good sample right here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5L6Ur/10/

some code in short:

```
 $(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));
    });
    var changecount = 0;
    $.address.change(function(e) {
        if (typeof e !== 'function') {
            $('span').html(changecount++);
        }
    });
 });​
```

Comment: Did you download jquery.address-1.5 from first link I provided?

Comment: @MUG4N yes, i included the the file right after `jquery` `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.address-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.address.value($(this).attr('href'));
    });
    var changecount = 0;
    $.address.change(function(e) {
        if (typeof e !== 'function') {
            $('span').html(changecount++);
        }
    });
});
</script>`

Comment: @MUG4N  getting errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined jquery.address-
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'change' of undefined `

Comment: @MUG4N found the solution, `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>`

Answer (score 4):

You should:

1. Set `location.hash` when page state changes.
2. When `location.hash`
   changed by user (for example, by pressing back button) render
   appropriate page contents.