# Simple jquery slider freezes on browser previous

Tags: jquery, freeze, slidetoggle, sliding

I've done a really simple jQuery slider

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Like this. It works perfectly, `div`'s are hidden and they display when you hover the `li` item, but there's a problem. When you press the "back" button in browser sometimes the `slidetoggle` "freezes" in the "opened" position (meaning the `div` is displayed) and they start working backwards. Any ideas for fix?

Comment: How does `hover` make something into a slider? And do you have an example of that? I can't see why clicking back button will make your script freeze.

Comment: Here's something i forgot to add. The li's hovered are links, and the bug occurs when u go to link and then press the "back" button in browser.
Also, it does not always occurs, but it's more of random.

Answer (score 1):

Try sliding them up as soon as the document is ready, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > div').slideUp();
    $('li').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

This will assure that your divs are slide upwards and will prevent it from working 'backwards'.

Comment: Does not work sadly. Is there an jquery function that catches user pressing "back" button in browser?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638292/after-travelling-back-in-firefox-history-javascript-wont-run and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462511/is-there-a-way-using-jquery-to-detect-the-back-button-being-pressed-cross-browse