# Enable a previously disabled button upon clicking browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This seems simple enough but can't determine what event should I look in to.

Sample code:

```js
let forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
forms[0].addEventListener('submit', () => {
  document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<form action="submit.html" method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The code above will disable the submit button upon submit. How do you enable it again when you hit the browser back button?

Comment: I think this one answers your Question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if the user clicked the "back" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008806/how-to-detect-if-the-user-clicked-the-back-button)